# module to display external db articles category

Tags: php, joomla, path, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5

I am trying to create a new module (joomla) that will display articles from a same category from an external db that is on the same server.
I am trying to modify a native joomla module that do the trick using the internal tables. (internal tables : _asso,  external tables : _rsc)

I changed that code (native module)

```
 $com_path = JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/';
```

with that

```
$com_path = '/homez.420/kmxsiksf/rsc/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';
```

but I got this error:

**Fatal error:** require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/homez.420/AAAAAA/rsc/components/com_cont ent/helpers/route.phprouter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /homez.420/AAAAAA/asso/modules/mod_articles_category/helper.php on line 14

Am I mistaken or is there a security in the .Htaccess or somewhere in Joomla that disable a module to display categories or modules from external tables?

Thanks!

Ps : The native module code starts like that:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$com_path = JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/';
require_once $com_path.'router.php';
require_once $com_path.'helpers/route.php';

JModelLegacy::addIncludePath($com_path . '/models', 'ContentModel');
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the asked question, there is no Joomla security to prevent display of anything that you mention.  I can't speak to your .htaccess settings, but that's highly doubtful.

Comment: Thanks a lot GDP so that is a good new! I keep trying! Have a good day!